# Ruby ODT file open Zip/Zip

Tags: ruby, xml, rubygems, zip, irb

I am trying to access the insides of an ODT file. I'll run it through IRB and it will work perfectly fine but when I try and write a script to do it, it fails with this error:

```
./replace_odf.rb:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
from ./replace_odf.rb:3
```

Here is my code when ran through IRB. As you can see towards the end, it can access the file.

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'zip/zip'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> odt = Zip::ZipFile.open('java.odt')
=> java.odt
irb(main):004:0> odt.entries.each do |entry|
irb(main):005:1*   puts entry.name
irb(main):006:1> end
mimetype
Configurations2/statusbar/
Configurations2/accelerator/current.xml
Configurations2/floater/
... etc
```

Here is my script code. When ran, it gives the error posted above.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'zip/zip'
require 'rexml/document'

odt = Zip::ZipFile.open('java.odt')
file1 = odt.entries[0]

odt.entries.each do |entry|
puts entry.name if entry.name =~ /\.xml$/
end

puts odt.read("mimetype")
xml = odt.read("content.xml")
doc = REXML::Document.new(xml)
doc.root.each_element do |o|
    o.each_element do |i|
        puts i
    end
end
```

Comment: Yes I know there's some pointless lines of code. Disregard those.. :)

Comment: Which Ruby verison are you using? In `ruby 1.9.3-p125`, `rubygems` is `require`d by default.

Comment: It's completely up to date. I tried taking that line out, still no go